# ¿Cómo realizar pruebas unitarias en android studio 1.3.2?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pruebas-unitarias

Necesito saber como realizar las pruebas unitarias en android studio a mi aplicación.

Comment: Todo lo que necesitas esta contenido en la pagina de desarrolladores para android, contiene tambien algunos videos.

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/index.html

Comment: Mirate también la preview de Android Studio 2.2 incorporan mejoras en este aspecto

Answer (score 1):

Solo para aclarar los comentarios que te hicieron que resuelven la consulta (así la podemos dar como cerrada)

1. Las pruebas unitarias en Android se realizan típicamente utilizando JUnit como es tradicional en Java.Como dice @Max Sandoval [esta es](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/index.html) la documentación puntual de Android.
2. Es altamente recomendable que actualices a una version más moderna de AS, ya que incluyen varios arreglos y mejoras de performance como Instant build. Como menciona @Webserveis en Android studio 2.3 (actualmente en release candidate) hay una nueva función para "grabar" test unitarios. Básicamente uno usa la app y AS genera el código del test unitario.